# Toggle AppShell on button click in Xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have AppShell that I pull from the side to show but I want to achieve this on button click  to toggle AppShell. I am not using the default AppShell navbar so I disabled the `Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False"` since its not needed.

I want to achieve this with the custom button to toggle AppShell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open it with this , true to open or false to close

```
  private void Bottommenu3_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    
        Shell.Current.FlyoutIsPresented = true;
    }
```